# ​[Запрос] на удаление

Tags: обсуждение, статус-запланировано, удаление-метки, замена-меток

Есть метка [запрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81).

- Неоднозначная. Где-то это запрос в базу данных, где-то http-запрос (точнее, [метод HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B)).
- Не добавляет информации к вопросу. Если [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), то и так ясно, что речь пойдет о запросах.

Следовательно, это мета-метка. Предлагаю проработать вопросы с этой меткой.

- Если уже есть [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) или одна из меток конкретных субд, то просто убрать эту метку.
- Если вопрос о базах данных, но вышеуказанных меток нет — заменить на подходящую.
- Если речь о http, заменить на метку для http (какую?).

> **Недостаточно просто удалять метку из вопросов! Улучшайте каждый обрабатываемый вопрос, насколько это возможно.**

Comment: А было принято какое-то решение по поводу http? может по аналогии с англ.СО http://stackoverflow.com/tags/httprequest/info + http-GET, http-POST, http-PUT and etc.

Comment: @Vartlok не было, ваше предложение мне нравится. Завтра подробнее посмотрю. Может, развернутый ответ напишете?

Answer (score 1):

На счет HTTP, предлагаю сделать метку по аналогии с англ.СО, т.е. [httprequest](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httprequest). [Описание метки на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httprequest/info). Плюс к этому, использовать метку конкретного метода, который нужен вопрошающему, например [http-post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post).

Comment: Мы обычно переводим метки, насколько это возможно. Как насчёт [tag:http-запрос]? А синонимом будет [tag:httprequest].

Comment: @NickVolynkin это наверное странная придирка, но не будет ли проблемно, постоянно переключать раскладку? Если таких меток будет много, это будет раздражать. И будет труднее искать такие метки.

Comment: там есть во-первых автоподстановка, а во-вторых замена на синоним.